# Django passing HTML objects into template as plain text

Tags: html, django, dom, zinnia

This feels like a really silly issue, but I'm confused by the behavior of django-zinnia, a blog creation module.

When I test enter a plain text post, it appends each sentence with html < p > tags the browser doesn't read as html.

Example, if I enter this into the database (no html):

[image: django admin]

The entry from the db renders on page itself like this as if the < p > markup was plain text:

[image: page]

[image]

Within Zinnia, these html tags are being generated as part of the {{ object_content }} object in _entry_detail_base.html

```
<div class="entry-content">
     {{ object_content }}
</div>
```

I've looked through the entry.py models within Zinnia and I'm having trouble identifying where these tags are coming from or how they're being passed in in a way the browser doesn't interpret them for what they are (html). Is there a filter I can apply that might solve this? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's  the default behavior for Django templates. Use `{{ object_content|safe }}` or `{% autoescape off %} {{ object_content }} {% endautoescape %}` (for multiple variables) to prevent html entities from being escaped.

Note that using the `safe` filter doesn't automatically mean the output is not escaped if you use another filter after it.

Comment: Perfect. Went with {% autoescape off %} {{ object_content }} {% endautoescape %}. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Zinnia's source code: https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/templates/zinnia/_entry_detail_base.html

It's using `|safe` template tag:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    {{ object_content|safe }}
</div>
```