# Django variable to javascript '&' character

Tags: javascript, django

So when I am trying to pass a list of country codes to javascript, it does replaces the single quotes -> `'`   with `&#39;`
Now I tried to replace all of those with a regular expression, but it would not work. I'm wondering why it will not work to just have those single quotes

```
function drawRegionsMap() {

        for (item in {{countries}}) {
            item.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
        }
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            {{countries}}
        );
```

In the javascript it's this:

```
function drawRegionsMap() {

for (item in [[&#39;Country&#39;], [&#39;AU&#39;], [&#39;AT&#39;], [&#39;BE&#39;], [&#39;BO&#39;], ... [&#39;LI&#39;], [&#39;MC&#39;], [&#39;ID&#39;]]) {
    item.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
}
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [[&#39;Country&#39;], [&#39;AU&#39;], [&#39;AT&#39;], [&#39;BE&#39;], [&#39;BO&#39;], [&#39;CO&#39;], ... [&#39;ID&#39;]]
);
```

So do I need to pass this Django variable to the javascript a different way? Is this even possible? All help is appreciated

The error:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'`

Comment: Have you tried [just pasting the raw string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216207/django-passing-html-objects-into-template-as-plain-text) instead of the HTML encoded text?

Comment: Why don't you do `{% for item in countries %}`?

Comment: Because it's already in the right format @ShangWang

Comment: How are you passing a list of countries to javascript in views.py? Why are you having single quotes? Do you really need single quotes? If so, you could add them manually in javascript code instead of passing them with the country codes.

Comment: I have found it now! Thanks @MikeC! I had to do `{{countries|safe}}`, which was provided in the solutions in from that link

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly this is fixed by doing `{{countries|safe}}`. I believe that's being used to escape certain characters. Thanks Mike C for providing the link, the solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216207/django-passing-html-objects-into-template-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 0):

If safe isn't working try with escapejs it worked for me